# SQL Loader data insert: can we use default value as another column value?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying data import using SQL*Loader. During import, if col1 value is blank I need to replace it with col0 value. Like these I need to set default values for multiple columns.

I tried setting it as `DEFAULTIF col1=col0` by adding length check.   Assuming if col1 value is blank, its length will be 0 and it will use execute `defaultif` condition. But its giving error saying

> Expecting quoted string or hex identifier, found "col0".

Can someone help and explain how to set default value as another column value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `NVL` function call does the job.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (col0 number, col1 varchar2(10), col2 number);

Table created.
```

Control file: note `col2 "nvl(:col2, :col0)"` which will put `col0` value into `col2` if `col2` doesn't exist. In my example, it is the second row, `2,yyy,` which doesn't contain value for `col2` so it'll be populated with `col0` value, i.e. `2`.

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by ","
trailing nullcols
(
col0,
col1,
col2 "nvl(:col2, :col0)"
)

begindata
1,xxx,111
2,yyy,
3,zzz,333
```

Loading session & the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@xe control=test02.ctl log=test02.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet Kol 17 21:48:59 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * From test;

      COL0 COL1             COL2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 xxx               111
         2 yyy                 2
         3 zzz               333

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot,
Thanks for details, I tried the suggested option it worked correctly. I have 30+ columns with million rows. I am able to insert all in @9 mins.